# When clicking selected radiobutton it goes error

Tags: android, sql

I am going to make a simple app of collecting people's personal information. But now i have some problem of radio button.I want to add selected radiobutton values to sql.
Here is the code.

MainActivity:

```
public void add(View view){
    EditText fn  = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.first_name);
    EditText ln   = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.last_name);

    first_name=fn.getText().toString();
    last_name =ln.getText().toString();

    radio_group=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radio_gender);
     String gender=    ((RadioButton)this.findViewById(radio_group.getCheckedRadioButtonId())).getText().toString();

    pf.execSQL("INSERT INTO Persone VALUES('"+first_name+"','"+last_name+"','"+gender+"');");
}
```

Comment: Do you have any button selected by default? You should add a onCkeckedChangeListener on your RadioButtons

Answer (score 0):

You can somehow compare the Radio Button methods with the switch case.

Here is an example of how your code could look like:

```
public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view) {
    // Is the button now checked?
boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

// Check which radio button was clicked
switch(view.getId()) {
    case R.id.radio_pirates:
        if (checked)
            // Pirates are the best
        break;
    case R.id.radio_ninjas:
        if (checked)
            // Ninjas rule
        break;
}
}
```

So, practically you need to specify what happens when a specific Radio Button from your Radio Group is selected.

If you want a more detailed // to the point answer let me know in a comment and I will try to write the code you need using your Main Activity.